# How to edit specific portions of the File upload functionality in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, data-science

I am totally new to R programming (and StackOverflow too) and was working on a small R project using the Shiny package(It seemed a lot easier and in tune to my requirements). Now I need to upload a .csv file for which Shiny has already provided a template or say codes in the form of ui.R and server.R. But my problem is that the code snippet Shiny has provided contains a browse section as well as a checkbox section for Headers and radio buttons for selection of Separators(Comma,Semicolon,Tab) and Quotes (None,Double,Single).

[image: [1]].

Now I only need the browse section and not the header or Separator or Quotes so I modified  the script but the radio buttons don't seem to go.

```
# The code section starts here.
# Original Script provided by Shiny.
ui.R

library(shiny)

 ui <- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
 sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
            accept=c('text/csv', 
                     'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                     '.csv')),
  tags$hr(),
  checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
  radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
               c(Comma=',',
                 Semicolon=';',
                 Tab='\t'),
               ','),
  radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
               c(None='',
                 'Double Quote'='"',
                 'Single Quote'="'"),
               '"')
),
mainPanel(
  tableOutput('contents')
  )
 )
)


 server.R file

 library(shiny)

 server <- function(input, output) {
 output$contents <- renderTable({

# input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
# and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
# 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
# column will contain the local filenames where the data can
# be found.

inFile <- input$file1

if (is.null(inFile))
  return(NULL)

read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header, sep=input$sep, 
         quote=input$quote)
    })
    }

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

I was able to remove the header tick box section as shown in the second image 
[image: [2]]

but not been able to remove the radio boxes. Please advise on how to do that.Thanking everybody in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I correctly understood your question, but you can just simply remove the two `radioButtons()` and the `checkboxInput()` from `ui`:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
      tags$hr()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('contents')
    )
  )
)
```

And then remove or replace the three input variables (`input$header`, `input$set` and `input$quote`) from your `read.csv()` in `server`:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$contents <- renderTable({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=T, sep=";")
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was deleting the radio buttons section in ui.R but was modifying the read.csv portion in server.R as read.csv(inFile$datapath). Maybe that's why I was not getting the desired output.Thanks again for your prompt and valuable suggestion.It worked like a charm.